# Dragging cell values in fixed increments

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I'm using Microsoft Excel 2021

I wish to be able to drag the cells in a column down in increments of 22 for example I typed in this in a column

L25
L47

and ideally, when I drag this it turns into

L25
L47
***L69***
***L91***

However, what I get after highlighting the two cells and dragging is this

L25
L47
***L27***
***L49***
***L29***

Please help in what I can do as I do not wish to go through every cell.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have L25 and L47 in two cells. =L25 on top and =L47 at the bottom. When I drag them downwards after highlighting the two values, I get in order, L25 L47 L27 L49 L29. That is not what I want. What I want is if I drag the two, I get in order, L25 L47 L69 L91 L113. Basically, I do not wish to go through every cell, remove the values after L, and type in the value I want. That is too tedious

Comment: We need to see your spreadsheet.

Comment: `I have L25 and L47 in two cells. =L25 on top and =L47 at the bottom.` Please be more precise - `L25` is not the same thing as `=L25`.

Answer (score 7):

There is a difference if you have formulas in your cells:
`=L25`, `=L47`, etc. or text constants `L25`, `L47`, etc.
In the first case, when dragging, you will get the order:
`=L25`, `=L47`, `=L27`, `=L49`, `=L29`, `=L51`
In the second case, the order will be:
`L25`, `L47`, `L69`, `L91`, ...

Comment: Knowing this, one can use a workaround: 1. create the formula as a string using a quote sign at the beginning `'=L25` and `'=L47` 2. drag to auto-fill the column 3. copy the whole column to the clipboard (Ctrl+C) 4. paste everything into a text-editor (like notepad) 5. Copy again from the text-editor (this removes the formatting as string) 6. paste into excel an the text will be formulas again.

Comment: If you want we could add this to your answer as a solution to the immediate problem.

Comment: Instead of using external text editor you can use internal Office clipboard (not standard Windows clipboard).

Answer (score 4):

I tried the method you described and had no issue getting the sequence you need. I selected both cells, dragged down, and got L69, L91...

An alternative is to do it with a formula. Assuming you have "L25" in cell A1, writing the following formula in A2 and drag A2 down:

```
="L"&(RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-1)+22)
```

Another alternative is to write the following formula in any cell:

```
="L" & SEQUENCE(100, 1, 25, 22)
```

where:

- 100 is the number of lines/iterations you need
- 1 is the number of column
- 25 is the starting number (i.e. L25)
- 22 is the increment, i.e. the number added to the starting number at each iteration

Please note this will create an array formula ([see the related MS documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7))